# How can i call the function from main event into another method?

Tags: python, function

i just confused, how can i call the function into another method? here's the script.

```
def createTargetCamera(path):
  src = initArguments()


  return

if __name__ == '__main__':

  #read argparse
  args = initArguments()
  print (args.conf)

  cam = createTargetCamera(args)
  print (cam)
```

i want to call the variabel **args** into **createTargetCamera()** method. can some one please help me?

Comment: functions can be called not variables. If you explain in detail what you're doing here maybe we could help

Comment: You seem to be confused about the terminology. You don't "call a function or a variable into a method". I suggest you to read some basic tutorial before attempting to write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to return the value:

```
def createTargetCamera(path):
  src = initArguments() # can be replace by src = path
  return src

if __name__ == '__main__':
  #read argparse
  args = initArguments()
  print (args.conf)
  cam = createTargetCamera(args)
  print (cam)
```

Also, if "args", "path" and "src" are equal to initArguments(), you can avoid some of them.